# Train simulation game to compete against the driver of the train I am riding right now

Tags: android, game, simulation, travel

Train driving simulators like [Odawara Line Simulator](http://www.realrailway.com/odawara/simulator.html) or [Densha de Go!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densha_de_Go!) are popular in Japan.

Controls:

- Acceleration
- Brake

Goal:

- Stop within centimeters of the target place.
- Arrive exactly on time.
- The smoothest wins: no sudden brakes, slower in curves.

The games I have found work offline.
Instead, I want to compete against the driver of the train I am riding right now *(and potentially other players riding the same train)*.

Requirements:

- Find out which train I am currently riding, probably using GPS and trains data.
- Detect the instant at which the real train starts, using bell sound recognition and motion sensor, and let me start my simulated train at the same time.
- Take statistics about the real train's time and smoothness performance, probably using my device's sensors. Real-world distance errors are extremely rare, so this can be skipped.
- Compare statistics after both our trains have reached a stop at the next station.
- Runs on Android.

Bonus for weather impact (rain/snow makes the brakes less efficient), bonus if data collected from the players is used to improve the simulation model, huge bonus if the game and data are open source.

Comment: I don't believe such a thing exists as of today. If you want to build one, you could look in this direction: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1363203 . Good luck :)

Comment: There are kids games for the iPad that do some of what you do, but no where near the complexity you are looking for.

Comment: @VicAche: Interesting! As you have probably seen, the difference is that in that paper, the player and the real-world driver are the same person, whereas in my question the two are separate and compete against each other.

Comment: @CRSouser: Are these games similar to the Odawara Line Simulator I mentioned in my question? Or do they actually bring a more Augmented Reality experience than this?